# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, spring-security

Using Kubernetes, exactly the `kubectl apply -f ./auth.yaml` statement, i'm trying to run a Authorization Server in a pod, but when I check out the logs, this show me the following error:

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.6.13)

2022-12-07 01:33:30.099  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.v.s.msvc.auth.MsvcAuthApplication      : Starting MsvcAuthApplication v1.0-SNAPSHOT using Java 18.0.2.1 on msvc-auth-7d696f776d-hpk99 with PID 1 (/app/msvc-auth-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /app)
2022-12-07 01:33:30.203  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.v.s.msvc.auth.MsvcAuthApplication      : The following 1 profile is active: "kubernetes"
2022-12-07 01:33:48.711  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.k.client.KubernetesClientUtils     : Created API client in the cluster.
2022-12-07 01:33:48.913  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientAutoConfiguration' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2022-12-07 01:33:49.794  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=9e09a67e-4528-373e-99ad-3031c15d14ab
2022-12-07 01:33:50.922  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'io.kubernetes.client.spring.extended.manifests.config.KubernetesManifestsAutoConfiguration' of type [io.kubernetes.client.spring.extended.manifests.config.KubernetesManifestsAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-12-07 01:33:51.113  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.commons.config.CommonsConfigAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.commons.config.CommonsConfigAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-12-07 01:33:51.184  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerDefaultMappingsProviderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerDefaultMappingsProviderAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-12-07 01:33:51.187  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'loadBalancerClientsDefaultsMappingsProvider' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerDefaultMappingsProviderAutoConfiguration$$Lambda$420/0x0000000800f30898] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-12-07 01:33:51.205  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'defaultsBindHandlerAdvisor' of type [org.springframework.cloud.commons.config.DefaultsBindHandlerAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-12-07 01:33:51.311  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'kubernetes.manifests-io.kubernetes.client.spring.extended.manifests.config.KubernetesManifestsProperties' of type [io.kubernetes.client.spring.extended.manifests.config.KubernetesManifestsProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-12-07 01:33:51.412  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-12-07 01:33:51.419  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration$ReactorDeferringLoadBalancerFilterConfig' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration$ReactorDeferringLoadBalancerFilterConfig] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-12-07 01:33:51.489  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'reactorDeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.DeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-12-07 01:33:58.301  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9000 (http)
2022-12-07 01:33:58.393  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-07 01:33:58.393  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
2022-12-07 01:33:58.795  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-07 01:33:58.796  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 26917 ms
2022-12-07 01:34:01.099  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.security.core.userdetails.User       : User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder() is considered unsafe for production and is only intended for sample applications.
2022-12-07 01:34:02.385  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/villamzr/springcloud/msvc/auth/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
2022-12-07 01:34:02.413  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-12-07 01:34:02.677  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-12-07 01:34:02.991 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/villamzr/springcloud/msvc/auth/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.13.jar!/:2.6.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745) ~[spring-boot-2.6.13.jar!/:2.6.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:420) ~[spring-boot-2.6.13.jar!/:2.6.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.6.13.jar!/:2.6.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1317) ~[spring-boot-2.6.13.jar!/:2.6.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.6.13.jar!/:2.6.13]
        at org.villamzr.springcloud.msvc.auth.MsvcAuthApplication.main(MsvcAuthApplication.java:12) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[msvc-auth-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[msvc-auth-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[msvc-auth-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[msvc-auth-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.java:235) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java:63) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
        at org.villamzr.springcloud.msvc.auth.SecurityConfig.authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(SecurityConfig.java:51) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.villamzr.springcloud.msvc.auth.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$477933bf.CGLIB$authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain$1(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.villamzr.springcloud.msvc.auth.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$477933bf$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a983a242.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.villamzr.springcloud.msvc.auth.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$477933bf.authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[msvc-auth-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

This is the auth.yaml configuration.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: msvc-auth
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: msvc-auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: msvc-auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: villamzr/auth:latest
          name: msvc-auth
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
          env:
            - name: LB_USUARIOS_URI
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: msvc-usuarios
                  key: lb_usuarios_uri
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: msvc-auth
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: msvc-auth
```

this one is the pom.xml of the microservice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.villamzr.springcloud.msvc</groupId>
      <artifactId>curso-kubernetes</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>org.villamzr.springcloud.msvc.auth</groupId>
   <artifactId>msvc-auth</artifactId>
   <name>msvc-auth</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>18</java.version>
      <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-loadbalancer</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
         <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

and this one is the Securityconfig

```
package org.villamzr.springcloud.msvc.auth;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.OidcScopes;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.ClientSettings;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.UUID;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());  // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
                )
                // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
                // authorization server filter chain
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("12345")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("usuarios-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}12345")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri(env.getProperty("LB_USUARIOS_URI")+"/login/oauth2/code/msvc-usuarios-client")
                .redirectUri(env.getProperty("LB_USUARIOS_URI")+"/authorized")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .scope("read")
                .scope("write")
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }
}
```

**SOLUTIONS I TESTED BUT IT DOWS NOT WORK**

1. I changed the tomcat server version to 10.x
2. I added the jakarta-api dependency to pom.xml of microservice, with 3.x, 5.x and 6.x versions
3. I added the `@EnableWebSecurity`

**NOTES**

1. I'm using java 18
2. I'm using Oauth 2.1 and authorization server 1.0.0

Comment: I'd recommend Spring Boot 3.x.  It requires JDK 17 and uses the new Jakarta package.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I upgraded to Spring-Boot 3.0.0 and it works! Thanks! According to this document, it need compatibility with tomcat and spring secutiry 6.x https://spring.io/blog/2022/07/28/spring-authorization-server-is-going-1-0

Comment: Easy fix, thanks to Maven.  New version and voila!  Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 8):

I was using Spring Boot 3 but was missing:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this issue upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.

**Problem:** I had Tomcat as independent dependency in pom.xml instead of letting Spring handle that.

**Fix: Remove Tomcat from pom** and let Spring define Tomcat.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.75</version>
</dependency>
```

**TLDR:**
To diagnose: first check your dependency tree using maven:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

You should find 2 Tomcat. One associated with Spring similar to:

```
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.1:compile
```

And a second Tomcat:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.75:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:10.1.1:compile
```

By removing the following, you'll only have Spring injected Tomcat and problem will be solved:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.75</version>
</dependency>
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

How are you building your Docker image? Whatever method you're using, it appears you're not including a web server (eg Tomcat or Jetty) in that image.

Comment: Spring Boot include an embedded tomcat

Answer (score 0):

The latest Spring Cloud uses the new Jakarta package and it's missing in Spring Boot 2.x so if you recently updated your Spring dependencies try to check them first.

In my case downgrading to the previous spring-cloud version solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting IntelliJ with invalidating caches worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add this dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```